# Type error - not a function

Tags: solidity, react

I am trying to call a contract function from my frontend app.
However it keeps saying that "it is not a function".

I have read almost every post I have seen here. Most say to use `send.({from: <acount_num>})` which is exactly what I do. (Nevertheless, I have tried call() and even without any postfix - didn't work either)

I thought I had troubles in my contract, so checked it in Remix and it works fine.

Here is the function I am calling in my contract:

```
function addUSer (string memory _name) public {
    usersCount ++;
    users[usersCount] = User(usersCount, _name);
    emit UserAdded(usersCount, _name);
}
```

And here is where I call it:

```
  addUser = userName => {
this.setState({ loading: true })
this.state.giveNTake.methods.addUser(userName).send({from: this.account}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
  this.setState({ loading: false })
})
```

}

I also added this line, even though I'm not really sure what it's for (I have seen it in some tutorials)

```
    this.addUser = this.addUser.bind(this)
```

**In conclusion:** I am completely lost. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's the exact error message? What's `this.state.giveNTake`? How was it initialized? Are you sure it was initialized correctly when it is called? Do you have the correct ABI? Do you have the correct address?

Comment: Make sure you deployed or if you are using truffle u migrated after code change

Comment: I have the correct abi, and I have deployed and I have migrated + reset multiple time. Anyway, I found a working contract online, copied it and changed the names and logic to my contract --> now it works. I believe it was something with dependencies or incorrect version. Nevertheless, thanks for your help :)